# Matrix representation of Boolean algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, boolean-algebra

Is there such a thing as matrix representations of Boolean algebra?

Give a boolean algebra with finite elements {a,b,c...} and operations $\cap, \neg$, we can regard $\cap$ as matrix multiplication and we're free to define the "complement" of the matrices.

We want the matrix multiplication to preserve the structure of Boolean algebra.  I learned that it is impossible for both matrix addition and multiplication to correspond to the boolean $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Is it possible to apply representation theory to find such matrices?

By the way, the axioms of Boolean algebra are:

1. $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$
2. $a + b = b + a$
3. $a + a = a$
4. $-(-b) = b$
5. $b + (-b) = 1$
6. $-1 = 0$
7. $0 + a = a$
8. $a \cdot (b+c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$
9. $a \cdot b \equiv -(-a + -b)$

where $\cup$ is denoted as + , $\cap$ as $\cdot$, and $\overline{x}$ as $-x$.

Here I try to convert the axioms to multiplicative form and eliminate the additive operations:

1. $(ab)c = a(bc)$   --- associativity
2. $ab = ba$ --- commutativity
3. $aa = a$ --- idempotency
4. $-(-a) = a$
5. $a(-a) = 0$
6. $-1 = 0$
7. $0a = 0$

Axiom 3 implies that the matrices are projection matrices.

What else needs to be done?

Comment: You really want matrix representations of Boolean rings (to convert a Boolean algebra to a Boolean ring, you use symmetric difference as addition instead of intersection). The module theory of Boolean rings is relatively straightforward, at least in the finite case, since finite Boolean rings are semisimple.

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful!